# Documenting a property-namespace inside a class

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How to document a property-namespace inside a class?

```
/**
 * @constructor User
 * @param forename
 * @param surname
 */
function User(forename, surname) {

    /**
     * How to document such a property-namespace?
     */
    this.name = {
        /**
         * How to document such a property?
         */
        first: forename,

        /**
         * How to document such a property?
         */
        second: surname
    };

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Using `@namespace` and `@property` does work, but it is displayed under `Namespaces` instead of `Members` or `Properties`, and only as a link that takes me to a separate page, which is awkward, since I'm documenting just a single class. Even worse, such a namespace appears on the list of global namespaces also. Seems like a bad solution. Is there a better one?

Comment: Can't you use `@namespace`, `@memberof` and `@property`? That's what I get when googled.

Comment: @mostruash And what about the contained properties?

Comment: @mostruash that does work, but takes me to a separate namespace documentation page, which is awkward, since it is the same class I'm documenting.

Comment: That behaviour is documented by jsdoc in their `@property` docs. I guess you can replace `@namespace` with `@member`.

Comment: @mostruash good guess, the combination of `@member` and `@property` does work nicely! You can post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
/**
 * @constructor User
 * @param forename
 * @param surname
 */
function User(forename, surname) {

    /**
     * @member {Object} User.name
     *
     * @property {String} forename
     *
     * @property {String} surname
     */
    this.name = {
        forename: forename,
        surname: surname
    };

}
```

Thanks @mostruash!